# How to get city information of Artist in Spotify?

Tags: api, spotify

I'm using Spotify API and I want to get city information of Artist, but not found in Spotify Dev.
Shortly, I can get "where are they listening" tab.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7aHP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible unfortunately, Spotify doesn't provide this through the API. They also don't provide it through the open web client so you can't scrape it. It only appears in the desktop application.

Comment: Every noise at once is from 2013, it's possible the circumstances around scraping/the API endpoints generally were more permissive back then